# Forking a application with new terminal for its separate input and output with control transferred to it

Tags: c, cygwin, fork

I am forking a child process and execl a BinaryApp.exe in that child process. However, I want a separate terminal window for newly forked BinaryApp.exe and control transferred to that terminal window so that it can detect any key strokes. Also by separating terminal windows, I can show interprocess communication more straightforwardly as parent and child process will output in their respective terminal windows. I am using cygwinb20 on Windows.

I have written a code for forking BinaryApp.exe but it shows its output in the same window as its parent. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    pid_t Pid;
    int ret;
    printf("Main Program\n Initializing processe...\n");

    Pid = fork();
    if (Pid >= 0) /* fork succeeded */
    {
        if (Pid == 0) /* fork() returns 0 for the child process */
        {
            ret = execl("../BinaryApp.exe","BinaryApp.exe",(char*)NULL); 
            if(ret == -1) {
                perror("execv - BinaryApp.exe");
            }                   
         }
    }
    else /* failure */
    {
        perror("fork - BinaryApp.exe");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Doing other things
}
```

Comment: Terminal is a program. If you want to run it, you need to `exec` it.

Comment: Please [see here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sh.1p.html). In particular option `-c` might be of interest to you.

Comment: @n.m. even if I run teminal in the forked new process, how to run BinaryApp.exe in that?

Comment: @alk It would be best if by just executing main process each child process gets forked and execute appropriate binary as written in the execl. Is it possible?

Comment: cygwinb20 ?? It is 20 years old. Any reason to use such ancient version ?

Comment: @matzeri No particular reason except that our guide has made us setup cygwinb20. I will ask her. Is it not possible with use of cygwinb20?

Comment: "how to run BinaryApp.exe in that" Unfortunately this seems to be a rather convoluted business in Mac OS X. You may want to ask a separate question to that effect ("how to start the terminal with my app already running in it?"), or search for existing questions.